# Why do some people claim that quantum physics and General relativity theory will never get along?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

As far as I know quantum physics and General relativity theory get along.
So Why do some people claim that quantum physics and General relativity theory will never get along?

Mathematically, What is contradiction between quantum physics and General relativity theory?

Comment: Quantum field theory and general relativity don't get along if that's what you're asking. Quantum mechanics and special relativity get along just fine and indeed the result is quantum field theory.

Comment: @Qmechanic
This question is different, I edit it and explained how

Comment: $\uparrow$ How?

Comment: To substantiate Qmechanic's question - in what way are the answers in the duplicate not *mathematical* aspects of the incompatibility between QM and GR?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9875/2451